# qt QString to char []

Tags: qt, char, qstring

I try to use the algorythm permutations of a string.
It works well if I do

```
void MainWindow::on_algo_clicked()
    {
    QString letters;
    letters = this->ui->myletters->text();
QMessageBox msgbox;
msgbox.setText(letters);
msgbox.exec();
string lettersString = letters.toUtf8().data();
char str[] = "ABC";
    int n = strlen(str);
    permute(str, 0, n-1);
      }
```

with the `char str[] = "ABC"`
I want to replace "ABC" by the value of letters (a qlineedit). I can display letters in a QMessageBox.
I try a lot of conversions for convert the QString "letters" to a string value (letters.toUtf8 .to StdString .......) but I always have some errors with this part of code : `char str[] = lettersString;`
I really don't understand.
I have read a lot of topic here and over internet but nothing works.
I'm sure I missunderstood something.

---

After hours of research and a lot of try I write this code and it seems to work it makes the permutation with the letters in my Qlineedit.

However I don't understand why it's working and why I'm not able to use c_str or the others solutions.

This is not a good solution if I don't understand exactly the process. ;-)

```
void MainWindow::on_algo_clicked()
    {
    QString letters = this->ui->myletters->text();
//QMessageBox msgbox;
//msgbox.setText(letters);
//msgbox.exec();
//string lettersString = letters.c_str();
//std::string lettersString;
QByteArray arraylettersUTF8 = letters.toUtf8();
char* lettersString = arraylettersUTF8.data();
QMessageBox msgbox;
msgbox.setText(lettersString);
msgbox.exec();
//lettersString = letters.toStdString();
    char* str = lettersString;
    int n = strlen(str);
    permute(str, 0, n-1);
      }
```

Comment: A `std::string` is not the same thing as a `char []`. Either convert the `QString` to a `char*` with something like `letters.toLatin1().data()` or convert your std::string using `lettersString.c_str()`.

Comment: I try to use lettersSting.c_str() but c_str() is not recognize as a function. Maybe I forget a #include in my headers.
My #include are
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QString>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

Comment: Maybe I misread your code. What is `string` in your code? I assumed it was a `std::string`, but it must be something else?

Comment: "letters" is a QString and I try to convert it to a standard String like "ABC" (I called it lettersString) which works with char str[] = lettersString;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the QString class has a method to convert an object to a std::string

here the doc: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toStdString

after you have the std::string you can call the method **c_str**

```
const char* c_str() const ;
```

Comment: I try to do that std::string lettersString = letters.toStdString(); 
and std::string lettersString = letters.toUtf8().constData();
so lettersString is a basic string but I have no success with const char* c_str() lettersString;